# Bootstrap collapsible on show

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I am using Bootstrap accordion menu http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse and I want it to have little + sign in front of text when collapsible is not collapse and little - sign in front of text when collapsible is collapsed. I am using the following event listeners

```
$('.collapse').on('show', function(e){
        $('.collapsed-status').innerHTML('- ');
    });
    $('.collapse').on('hide', function(e){
        $('.collapsed-status').innerHTML('+ ');
    });
```

jQuery is also included so there shouldnt be problem with these selecotrs. My collapsible looks like this

```
<div class="accordion-group produkty">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#produkty" href="#collapse1"><span class="collapsed-status">+ </span>Test</a>
                        <ul id="collapse1" class="collapse">
                        <li>›› Test</li>
                        <li>›› Test</li>
                        <li>›› Test</li>
                        <li>›› Test</li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
```

but it is not working. I have tried to fix it but I cant get it working. Thanks in forward for your help

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can toggle the class of a element with the following code:

```
$('.accordion').collapse();

$('.accordion').on('shown hidden', function(e){
    $(e.target).siblings('.accordion-heading').find('.accordion-toggle i').toggleClass('icon-plus icon-minus');
});
```

In the code above I'm toggle between showing a plus icon and a minus icon, which you can use since your using bootstrap.

You simply need to add an icon before each heading like so:

```
<div class="accordion-heading">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
      <i class="icon-minus"></i> Heading 1
    </a>
</div>
```

The result is the following:

[image]

Here is the jsFiddle so you can see a live demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/s8dAd/4/

Comment: looks like there is some problem with my javascript because I have tried writing $('.accordion').hide(); to head inside <script> tags to jus test function of selectors and working of javascript but it didnt hide accordions. I have also tried to change it and hide any other element but it didnt work either.

Comment: To test functions on load you would need to add them inside $(document).ready() like so: $(document).ready(function() {
      alert("document ready occurred!");
});